# Xamarin Binding Libraries in Common Forms Project

Tags: c#, xamarin, dependencies, monodevelop

In Xamarin, I am trying to create a library which can be used from the main Forms project. This library needs to be created out of binding projects for iOS and Android as both make use of native code written in Objective-C and Java, respectively.

To do this, I created a common interface `IExample` in the shared project "Binding Project Interface" and implemented this interface in both binding projects as `ExampleiOS` and `ExampleAndroid`. Then I instantiate the implementations from each of the platform's App Projects and pass them into the Common App Project.

This is where I run into trouble, because both the Common App Project and the Binding Projects reference the Binding Project Interface. As a result, the platform App Projects inherit `IExample` from two separate places and I get the error:

`The imported type 'IExample' is defined multiple times`

How can I modify the framework so the code for the current binding project is accessible from the Common App Project?

I cannot remove reference A because then the common project does not know about the interface it needs to be passed an instance of. I cannot remove references B or C because then the binding projects cannot implement the interface. I cannot remove references D or E because the app projects need to instantiate the implementations in the binding project. I cannot remove references F or G because the app projects need to have access to the common code in order to pass it the instantiated implementation.

An arrow from one project to another indicates that the first project is a reference of the one it's pointing to:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Common Binding Project should have been a PCL project, not a shared project. As a shared project, the files were merely copied into the referencing projects and the interface was thus actually being compiled twice.